If $G$ is a topological group and $H\leqslant G$, then is $G/H$ always locally compact?
I was studying the book 'Real and Functional Analysis' by Lang, and I came across the following statement in Chapter XII (page 311):

In particular, we see that the map $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H$ is an open mapping, i.e., maps open sets onto open sets. All open subsets of $G/H$ may be written in the form $VH$ with $V$ open in $G$. In particular, $G/H$ is locally compact.

Here $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
I know that if $G$ is locally compact, then $G/H$ is locally compact. The problem is that, up to this point in the text, the author never assumes that $G$ is locally compact. In fact, we are not even considering that $G$ is Hausdorff. This statement in bold, in all this generality, seems false to me, and I think I have a counterexample: Take the additive group $G=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, with $\mathbb{Q}$ having the usual topology; then, if $\mathbb{Q}\cong H\leqslant G$, we have $G/H\cong\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact.

Is this counterexample valid? Or am I missing something?
If the statement made in the book is true, then how can it be proven?


Perhaps the author forgot to add the assumption that $G$ is locally compact. After all, if we take $H={e}$ then the quotient will be homeomorphic to $G$, right?
